# Clearing Magento statistics

Tags: magento2

I'm deploying my Magento online store soon but I'm a bit paranoid in testing and I want to repeat my test scenarios in production.

I already found a safe way to delete my test orders but I'm having trouble finding a way to reset statistics such as "Last Search Terms", "Top Search Terms", "Best sellers" etc

Can anyone help?

PS I don't want to delete ir from database directly, I want to use Magento objects so I can have the guarentee that magento DB is not messed up and mantains it's integrity !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will do the job.

```
<?php
                
                use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
                include('../app/bootstrap.php');
                header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
                
                $bootstrap     = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
                $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
                $state         = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
                $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
                
                    $order_collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection();
            
                    foreach ($order_collection as $order)
                    { 
                        $id = $order->getId(); // your order_id 
                        $order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
                        $registry->register('isSecureArea','true');
                        $order->delete();
                        $registry->unregister('isSecureArea'); 
                    }
            
                    $collection = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\CollectionFactory::class)->create();
                    foreach($collection as $row)
                    {
                        $row->delete();
                    }
            
                    $resource       = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
                    $connection     = $resource->getConnection();
                      
                    $connection->delete( 'report_event', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'report_viewed_product_index', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily', []);
                
                    $connection->delete( 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly', []);
                    $connection->delete( 'sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily', []);
                }
                ?>
```

**Heads up:**

1. This is only meant to be used as a executable script and not within magento (it ha sa lot of calls to objectManager wich can be dangerous)
2. This will eliminate all orders, bestsellers, views and search terms